# Is there a way to add different fonts to different properties in Typography using material ui @next React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, material-ui

```
const fontWeightMedium = 500;
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    // Use the system font.
    fontFamily:
    'forzaBook',
    fontWeightMedium,
    body1: {
      fontWeight: fontWeightMedium,
    },
    button: {
      fontStyle: 'italic',
    },
    caption: {
      fontWeight:100
    }
  },
  palette: {
    primary: orange,
    secondary: {
      ...grey,
      // A400: '#00e677',
    },
    contrast: 'white',
    error: red,
  }
});
```

Here is what I am currently using to change the font and some Typography properties. But I need to change the font for the caption. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the fontFamily on a per Typography-variant basis:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'forzaBook', // Change the default
    caption: {
      fontFamily: "openSans" // Change a specific variant
    }
  },
});
```